# I am wondering what "back" means here?

Tags: intransitive-preposition, locative

A. He backs.

B. He is back.

C. he will be back

What is the difference in meaning between these?

Comment: Usage (C) reminds me of Arnold Schwarzenegger's famous line from _The Terminator_, when he says "I'll be back."  Schwarzenegger said it with a very strong Austrian accent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Back* in B. and C. is a locative expression meaning, approximately, "once again at the place he left earlier". The *Cambridge  Grammar of the English Language* would classify it as an "intransitive preposition", meaning one which does not take an explicit object. Its real-life object can be inferred from context; we have no way of knowing whether *back here* or *back there* or *back home* is meant.

Locative expressions may serve syntactically as nominals, adjectivals or adverbials; in these two sentences, where it is the complement of the complement *be*, it is best understood as an adjectival, naming the location of the subject. The two sentences differ only in tense—the time to which they refer.

*Backs* in A. is an intransitive verb meaning "moves backward". It is very unusual to see it by itself this way; ordinarily it would be followed by a locative expression describing a goal or path: *He backs up*, *He backs away*, *He backs into the corner*, or something of that sort.

Comment: There is an alternate interpretation of A... particularly common with Kickstarter and other crowdsourcing - "Backs" meaning supports. Just part of my thoughts when I looked at this one.

Comment: @Catija: But that's a transitive verb, which *requires* an object, so it cannot be used as it is in OP's sentence A. The intransitive meaning is *just* possible. ... Note that there are also transitive versions which take a locative complement in addition to the direct object: *He backed the car into the garage*, *He backed him into a corner*. The first can dispense with the locative, but the second cannot.

Comment: Maybe obvious, but just to be complete: B is present tense while C is future.

Comment: @StoneyB: The lack of object assumes that the OP is giving complete example sentences.  And in general use it would, I think, be much more common to say "backs up" rather than just "backs".  (Though even as I write, I see that has two distinctly different meanings :-))

Comment: @jamesqf That's exactly what I say in my last paragraph.